# How to append child node and create component dynamically with angular 2

Tags: angular

I have angular2 component. I need

- locate node in the template
- append child node to located node
- create other component inside the child node dynamically.

Is it possible with Angular 2?

If the node already exists in the template the solution is known.

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "<div #node></div>"
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("node", { read: ViewContainerRef }) nodeView;

  constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentResolver) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(MyComponent)
      .then((factory: ComponentFactory<MyComponent>) => {
         MyComponent instance = this.nodeView.createComponent(factory);
       });
  }
}
```

In that way the problem is to find dynamic equivalent of @ViewChild directive.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: "dynamic" only means in code not in template.

Comment: There is no dynamic way. `@ViewChild()` or injecting `ViewContainerRef` from the current component through the constructor are the options

Comment: This short blog post by Netanel Basal https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d is exactly what you're looking for.